# SQL SUM Values need and then AVG of 2 Tables

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, sum, case, average

From this it is possible for the following :

```
   TABLE 1
   Id | final | Date
   ------------------
    1    236    02-11-14
    2     10    07-01-12
    3     58    09-02-10

   TABLE 2
   Id | final | Date
 ------------------
   1     330    02-11-14
   2     5      07-01-12
   3     100    09-02-10
```

ADD both Table 1 and Table 2 Sum'd values(column final), and then work out the AVG number from this and create this as another column average, THEN if table2 for example SUM'd original amount (before the AVG) is higher than Table 1 SUM'd amount create another column and print in that column 'Tbl2 has the higher amount' and vise verser if table 1 had the higher amount.

End result Column wise table would look like this :

```
  |tb1_final_amount|tb2_final_amount|Avg_Amount|Top_Score_tbl


   |tb1_final_amount|tb2_final_amount|Avg_Amount|Top_Score_tbl
        304              435           369.5      tb2 has highest score
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output

Comment: NoDisplayName i have changed the expected results. Removing the ID Column

Comment: i want to see records in the expected result

Comment: I've added the results as expected

Comment: NB: The answers by jpw and JohnS give different results for the average. They both can't be right!

Comment: @JohnS Indeed. I guess the OP wanted something else than what was shown as output sample (which is what my answer produced).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick!:

```
--SET UP Table1
CREATE TABLE Table1 (ID INT, final INT, [Date] DATETIME)
INSERT Table1 VALUES (1, 236, '20141102')
INSERT Table1 VALUES (2,  10, '20120107')
INSERT Table1 VALUES (3,  58, '20100209')

--SET UP Table2
CREATE TABLE Table2 (ID INT, final INT, [Date] DATETIME)
INSERT Table2 VALUES (1, 330, '20141102')
INSERT Table2 VALUES (2,   5, '20120107')
INSERT Table2 VALUES (3, 100, '20100209')

-- Query
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.TableName = 'Table1' THEN T.final
           ELSE 0
      END) AS tb1_final_amount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN t.TableName = 'Table2' THEN T.final
           ELSE 0
      END) AS tb2_final_amount,
  AVG(T.final) AS Avg_Amount,
  ISNULL((
          SELECT
            'Table1'
          FROM
            Table1 T1
          WHERE
            SUM(CASE WHEN t.TableName = 'Table1' THEN T.final
                     ELSE 0
                END) > SUM(CASE WHEN t.TableName = 'Table2' THEN T.final
                                ELSE 0
                           END)
         ), 'Table2')
FROM
  (
   SELECT
    'Table1' AS TableName,
    final
   FROM
    Table1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
    'Table2',
    final
   FROM
    Table2
  ) AS T
```

Comment: Thanks you Guys for all your help, That's Brillant

Answer (score 1):

This is one way (of many) to do this. You can sum up the two tables and use them as derived tables in a query like so:

```
select 
    tb1_final_amount, 
    tb2_final_amount, 
    (tb1_final_amount+tb2_final_amount)/2.0 as Avg_Amount, 
    case 
       when tb1_final_amount < tb2_final_amount then 'tb2 has highest score' 
       else 'tb1 has highest score' 
    end as Top_Score_tbl 
from 
    (select SUM(final) as tb1_final_amount from TABLE1) t1, 
    (select SUM(final) as tb2_final_amount from TABLE2) t2
```